# Jquery not disabled the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input tag not disabled.This is my code.Please help me.

```
var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
input.prop('disabled', true);    
input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Add complete code and HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find the input with value instead of using Attribute value selector.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Also you can use `closest()` to traverse up to desired parent.

*Script*

```
var value = $(this).val();
var input = $('input').filter(function(){
    return value == $(this).val();
}).prop('disabled', true);    
input.closest('li').addClass('disabled');
```